# Adding comments on an iPhone doesn't always work

Tags: bug

I've noticed a few times over the last month that occasionally adding comments to posts don't go through; this is on the iPhone.

Has anyone else experienced this?

I can tap the button, 'add comment'; and an edit box opens; I can then write the comment; but then when it it comes to posting it, it won't go through: I'm left tapping on the button ineffectively...

Comment: I use SE almost exclusively on an iPhone, and I've never experienced this particular problem. I can imagine it happening if I'm in an area of bad coverage (eg the subway), though. Are you using the latest version of both the app and iOS?